# Getting Active X Component can't create object when trying to launch QTP through a batch file

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, qtp

I am trying to run QTP through a batch file in order to be able to schedule the run considering the following VBS code :

```
Set qtpApp = CreateObject("QuickTest.Application")
Set fsObj = CreateObject("ScriptingFileSystemObject")
Set qtpResObj = CreateObject ("QuickTest.RunResultsOptions")

qtpApp.Launch
qtpApp.Visible= True
ect...
```

I call this VBS through a batch file :

```
wscript "C:\QA\UVMS\RunTests.vbs"
```

However when running the batch file I get the error :

```
ActiveX component cannot create object SrciptingFileSystemObject
```

When trying to resgister scrrun.dll through command line :

```
regsvr32 scrrun.dll
```

I get the following error

```
the module scrrun was loaded but call to DllregisterServer failed
```

Any help please?

Comment: I have found out,  the issue is related to admin rights I had to open the command line as an asministrator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is also missing a dot - scripting.filesystemobject